# My Composer PHP project stucks at require '/vendor/autoload.php';

Tags: php, composer-php, require

Dear StackOverflow community,

iam really new to Composer so the solution might be easy but i dont get it.

My PHP file looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ServerStatusChecker</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php

        echo "1";

        require '/vendor/autoload.php';

        echo "2";

        use MinecraftServerStatus\MinecraftServerStatus;

        echo "3";

        $response = MinecraftServerStatus::query('mineplex.com', 25565);

        echo "4";

        if (! $response) {
            echo "The Server is offline!";
        } else {
            echo "<img width=\"64\" height=\"64\" src=\"" . $response['favicon'] . "\" /> <br>
                The Server " . $response['hostname'] . " is running on " . $response['version'] . " and is online,
                currently are " . $response['players'] . " players online
                of a maximum of " . $response['max_players'] . ". The motd of the server is '" . $response['description'] . "'.
                The server has a ping of " . $response['ping'] . " milliseconds.";
        }   
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my problem is that when i call the webpage it stays blank except from one debug `1`.

I am getting no visable error messages or similar.
So why this happens and/or what i am doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: What is your directory structure? Did composer install finish without errors?

Comment: Run composer and install packages through command line, It will make your life easy

Comment: @JakubJudas My index.php file is in ´/var/www/html/ServerChecker´ together with the ´composer.json´ and the ´vendor folder´. It installed with no visable errors

Comment: @AammadUllah i have installed the package through the command line

Comment: Just open command and move to the directory where you want to install a package and type composer require package name and hit enter.

Comment: @AammadUllah i did that in `/var/www/html/ServerChecker`

Comment: Does /vendor/autoload.php exists? Maybe you have some problem with paths? Will ./vendor/autoload.php work? Or ../vendor/autoload.php? What does echo \_\_dir\_\_ say?

Comment: Wow thank you `./vendor/autoload.php` worked

Answer (score 1):

Changed line 10 `require '/vendor/autoload.php';` to `require './vendor/autoload.php';` and it worked

Thanks @AammadUllah